# How to get back dual -boot options after GRUB has made it linux only

Tags: windows, linux, boot, grub, bootloader

I installed RHEL 4.0 on my PC which already had Widows 7 on it. it installed GRUB boot loader without giving dual -boot option -- it only gives the option to go to RHEL 4.0 . Is there a way for me to tell GRUB to also give me an option to boot into Windows 7 ?

**UPDATE** :
My menu.lst looks like below

```
[root@abacchu-lnx ~]# more /boot/grub/menu.lst
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You do not have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /, eg.
#          root (hd0,1)
#          kernel /boot/vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/sda2
#          initrd /boot/initrd-version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,1)/boot/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu

title Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS (2.6.9-89.0.11.ELsmp)
        root (hd0,1)
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.0.11.ELsmp ro root=LABEL=/1
        initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.9-89.0.11.ELsmp.img
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS (2.6.9-89.0.11.EL)
        root (hd0,1)
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.0.11.EL ro root=LABEL=/1
        initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.9-89.0.11.EL.img
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS (2.6.9-89.ELsmp)
        root (hd0,1)
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.ELsmp ro root=LABEL=/1
        initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.9-89.ELsmp.img
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS-up (2.6.9-89.EL)
        root (hd0,1)
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.EL ro root=LABEL=/1
        initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.9-89.EL.img
title Other
        rootnoverify (hd0,0)
        chainloader +1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an option to edit grub menu file, which usually resides in `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and contains a list of commands to load different OSes.

You would add another entry for your second (third) OS, Windows in your case, e. g.:

```
default=0
timeout=5

title Windows
    root(hd0,0)
    rootnoverify(hd0)
    chainloader +1

title RHEL
    root(hd0,1)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6...
    initrd /initrd-2.6...
```

Comment: `hd0` in `(hd0,0)` means that it's the first hard drive, and `0` meanst that your OS is in the first partition (numbering in many things related to computers usually starts from zero).

Comment: thanks. that did the trick. I just had to un-hide my menu and was able to get into windows.